# PHP MySQL Insert Code Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, insert

I am trying to insert some data in the database but it gives me a really confusing error

Now the error is:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')'

Code:

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` VALUES (''," .$username ."," . $password . "," . $date . "," .$email . ",1'"));
```

Comment: You're missing a couple of concatenation operators (`.`).  Also, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: I've removed my answer. Because there're so many errors. You should learn about basic PHP strings first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've worked it out now.
No more answers

Answer (score 0):

You forgot some dots over there.

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` VALUES (" .$username ."," . $password .  "," . $date . ","  .$email . ",1)");
```

Comment: @user2489187 You also got an extra `)` after the `"`. Try this: `$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members VALUES (" .$username ."," . $password . "," . $date . "," .$email . ",1)");`

Comment: Your error is the same as echo_Me's

Comment: I will work it out later.
None of your answers work

Answer (score 0):

you have many mistakes , you forgot points `.` you forget `)` .

**you should also specify the columns names**

this should work for you

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` (firstcolumn ,username , password ,date,email , lastcolumn) VALUES ('' ,'$username','$password','$date','$email',1 )  ");
                                               ^----------^--------^-----^----^-----^^---your columns
```

HERE genaeral rule how to use insert :

```
INSERT into table (column1 , column2 , column3) VALUES (value1 , value2 , value3)
```

Comment: @user2489187 check my updated answer , you should make your columns

Comment: Now The Error is Notice: Use of undefined constant query - assumed 'query' with your code echo_Me

Comment: have you replaced your columns by what i have wrote `your columns` exactly what the values you insert

Comment: make sure you do your columns as i wrote bellow the example

Comment: yes I have replaced the columns

Comment: @echo_Me: I'm sure he has missed `$` sign before `query` at some line of his code :P

Comment: i see that you insert `''` before username , so you should also use this column

Comment: I get confused with MySQL

Comment: heheeh you should convert to MYSQLI or PDO

Comment: I did miss out a $ but it still doesn't work

Comment: show your table and your code and we will see

Comment: I will work it out later.
None of your answers work

Answer (score 0):

Try this (replace x,y,z,a,b with column name):

```
$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `members` (`x`,`y`,`z`,`a`,`b`) VALUES ('','.$username.','.$password.','.$date .','.$email.','1'"));
```

You haven't used `'` and `"` in correct place.

Comment: I will work it out later.
None of your answers work

Answer (score 0):

write your query and add at the end

```
or die(mysql_error());
```

what it says?

Comment: I did. I did
if(!$query){
$query[0] = mysql_error();
return $query[0];
}